# C++11 initializer_list constructor marked "explicit"

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, explicit-constructor

Can I use explicit with an init-list ctor to make sure an expression like {a} doesn't result in unexpected implicit conversion? And another thought: **should** I be worried about it? Writing `{a}` is less likely to be a mistake than simply `a`, but on the other hand, it still may not be clear from the code that we're constructing an object through implicit conversion.

```
class Foo
{
    explicit Foo (std::initializer_list<Bar> ilist) { /*...*/}
};
```

Comment: Depending on what it is, I like it. I like being able to use `someFunctionWithVectorAsArgument({1, 2, 3});`.

Comment: I agree, but I pass the ilist to a constructor of another class, which is a template parameter not known to me, and I can't tell whether that class has the constructor marked explicit or not, or whether it's safe to use {1,2,3} like you do. That's why I'm asking, I wonder if it's dangerous like the common implicit conversions done when not using "explicit"

Comment: IMHO putting `explicit` on an initializer-list constructor is _always_ a bad idea. It has no advantage and just result in confusing or unexpected errors for reasonable attempts to construct the type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. It *does* result in the unexpected implicit conversion.

However, the unexpected implicit conversion is disallowed and the compiler will reject your program. That however doesn't stop the compiler to select or consider it. Example

```
 void f(Foo);
 void f(std::vector<Bar>);

 int main() {
   // ambiguous
   f({bar1, bar2, bar3});
 }
```

Comment: So does "explicit" do anything in this case? I'm not sure I understand. I want Temple<T> constructor to take an initializer list and pass it to a constructor of T which takes an initializer list. Does marking Templ<T>'s constructor as explicit have a useful effect?

Comment: And why does this answer contradict the other answer... it means one of you is giving a wrong answer without being aware of that...

Comment: @fr33domlover as I said, if "f(Foo)" is selected, the program is ill-formed (rejected by the compiler). The fact that the constructor is explicit does not influence the choice of what functions the compiler tries to executes. If `Foo` had another initializer list constructor that is not better than the `Bar` taking one, you would get an ambiguity aswell. If the `Bar` taking one is better, the compiler would choose the `Bar` taking one, and give you an error message because it would use an `explicit` constructor.

Comment: @fr33domlover I think he is confused about the form of argument passing. The rules of `explicit` are different for initializer list initialization than they are for normal initialization. So `Foo f = a;` will not *consider* `explicit` constructors (i.e it will just ignore them), but `Foo f = { a }` will not *allow* `explicit` constructors, but it *will consider* them.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can.  Whether you should really depends on the situation, although I think it would be rare in general.

Comment: Does explicit mean that any number of ilist items is not allowed, or just one item? In other words, does it make {1,2,3} illegal, or just {1} is illegal while {1,2,3} is still okay?

Comment: @fr33domlover: It means that particular constructor cannot be used implicitly.  If there is some other constructor that lets you create the object that isn't declared explicit, then that one might be used implicitly.

Comment: Then I'm removing the "explicit" keyword, I do want to enjoy the convenienve of {1,2,3}